# Is there a word for 'making offending sarcastic remarks'?

Tags: word-choice, slang, sarcasm

Is there a word (probably a verb to describe the action) for the below situation:

When someone throws a sarcastic remark to you, especially in front of other people, not in a playful manner but rather an offensive one, meaning to dampen you.

It could be more of a slang term, an "urbandictionary-word", than a conventional English word.

Comment: "belittle" e.g. He jumps on every opportunity to belittle me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a lot of such words and expressions (so I hope you'll resist the urge to select an answer prematurely). The one I'll propose is **cut down**.  Here are a couple sample usages:

> I didn't appreciate the way he **cut me down** during the meeting.
>   Maybe he **cut down** Susan during the meeting, but I don't think he did himself any favors.

The phrase is a shortened form of **cut someone down to size**, meaning "to put someone in their place."

It should be noted that the phrase *cut down* has [**several** meanings](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+down), so you'll want to provide ample context to make it clear what you are talking about.

If you wanted to use a noun rather than a verb, you could try **slap in the face**. It is slang for "an insult."

> Bob's remarks were a real slap in the face.

By the way, the word *real* in that example sentence means "serious," not "actual" (i.e., Definition #5, **not** Definition #1a, in [this dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/real)). Contrary to how it might be interpreted, that sentence **doesn't** mean that Bob was literally slapped in the face.

Comment: If the O.P. does want an Urban Dictionary-style term that is very slangy (though apparently used in some major-newspaper op-eds), I'd suggest **dis**, which is used with almost exactly the same meaning as **cut down**.

Comment: The "slap in the face" sounds a lot like bitchslap, i always wonder if bitchslap has another meaning rather than a physically slap http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bitchslap

Comment: @user49119 It has no other widely-recognized meaning, and the term is considered rather offensive in itself.

Comment: The two are worlds apart. _Slap in the face_ is almost always metaphorical, and is considered an acceptible way to convey a sharp insult, while _bitchslap_ would be considered vulgar, offensive, and coarse. Furthermore, _bitchslap_ would refer more to abusive behavior than a barbed insult. I'd have no problem using _slap in the face_ even when talking to my company president, but I'd never use _bitchslap_ in that setting. However, you have made my day with your comment. If you really did wonder if the two expressions were similar, then I'm confident ELL will someday graduate from beta. :^)

Comment: Personally, I would say *real* here is an intensifier ([sense 12 in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/real)).  Words with meaning similar to *real* tend to become intensifiers; others include *very*, *really*, *truly*, *honestly*, and *literally*.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you interpret it, but to me, the OP stated that *an ubandictionary-type word* is OK, not required. Either way, that's not really a *bitchslap* or a *dis*. Those both imply an insulting or offensive behavior. The key word for me was *dampen*, which I assumed meant *to hurt* or *deflate*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you will get is with ["sardonic"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/sardonic).

Answer (score 0):

Someone with a "biting" personality or who is prone to making "biting" remarks is making the kind of offensive, rude, and deragatory insults of which you speak. This can be true both in sarcastic and straight-forward situations, although typically biting satire is sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *[snark](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snark#Verb)* may be appropriate.  It means  “To express oneself in a [snarky](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snarky#Adjective) fashion”, where *snarky* means  “Snide and sarcastic; usually out of irritation, often humorously”.  Example:  “He snarked at her all through the meeting.”

Also consider verb *[backbite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backbite#Verb)*, “To make spiteful slanderous or defamatory statements about someone”  or  “To attack from behind or when out of earshot with spiteful or defamatory remarks”.

The phrase  “do him down” or  “do her down” means to denigrate someone by making critical remarks intended to damage the person's standing or reputation.

Comment: Snark was the first thing that came to mind. I had to ask myself if that was colloquial or not, but in common speech, *snark/snarky* would be most common.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would express this is:

> He's always **putting me down**.

This is similar to ["cut (someone) down"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11764/is-there-a-word-for-making-offending-sarcastic-remarks#answer-11766) and is an informal way to describe someone [belittling](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11764/is-there-a-word-for-making-offending-sarcastic-remarks#comment-20030) you. If it's more important to indicate a [snarky](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11764/is-there-a-word-for-making-offending-sarcastic-remarks#answer-11778) comment that you didn't appreciate, you might instead say:

> He made a joke **at my expense**.

To my knowledge, there is not a term that is specific to overly hurtful sarcasm, but if you trust context and tone to carry your meaning, you could also say:

> He's always **messing with me**.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the verbs 'calumniate','besmirch', 'asperse' or 'slander'.

```
She slandered/calumniated/aspersed/besmirched me in front of everyone that day
```

Comment: *Slander* has a specific legal meaning in some countries, so it may not be appropriate.  *Besmirch* is possible, but it's not terribly common and sounds rather formal.  (Usually someone's *reputation* or someone's *name* is besmirched, rather than the person themselves.)  *Caluminate* and *asperse* are very rare and may not be understood.

Comment: Slander is not applicable; aside from being a legal term, it implies making disparaging or untrue statements to damage someone's credibility or reputation. I think that the question is more referring to intentionally hurting someone's feelings. To be honest, while I'm familiar with *calumniate* and *asperse*, I've never heard a native speaker use them before. Only the most educated of speakers would understand what those words mean. And *besmirched* is more common, but it's *slightly* archaic/awkward.

Comment: "...not in a playful manner but rather an *offensive one*.." is what OP asks. I gave several options since the question isn't clear (telling us a specific sentence). *Slander* in this context is fine I think.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the best way would be: "S/he was very sarcastic about me".

In [Lowland] Scottish, it is often abbreviated to "sarky", e.g. "S/he was very sarky to me".

[The Chambers Thesaurus entry for **sarcastic** (link)](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=sarcastic&title=thes) is 
**adj**
ironical, satirical, mocking, snide, taunting, sneering, derisive, derisory, scornful, sardonic, jeering, scoffing, scathing, cynical, incisive, cutting, biting, caustic *formal* disparaging, acrimonious, acerbic, mordant *colloq.* sarky

You can take your pick from there, pretty much.

> S/he mocked me,
>   s/he taunted me,
>   s/he sneered at me,
>   s/he derided me,
>   s/he jeered at me,
>   s/he made a scathing comment about me,
>   s/he made a really cutting (or biting) remark about me,
>   s/he made a really caustic comment about me